# why, when i restart the terminal the environment variables are restarted?

Tags: linux

i do the next:

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

then to verify that all is correct :

mvn -version

and it works but when i close the terminal and open other terminal the environment variables are erased

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's how variables work. You're setting them for that session. If you want them to persist, put them in your `.profile` so they're set each time a new instance of your shell starts.

Comment: @user2268030 - No you have not. You have missed the `export` bit out!

Comment: ... and the line `export PATH=$M2:$PATH`.

Comment: yes you are right. now the code is these way: http://pastebin.com/iBFDCs2X  and then in the terminal i write: source /etc/profile and also i write echo $M2 and i can see that the path was added so i can execute the command : mvn -version and it works, but when i close the terminal and open other temrinal it don't work again, i write in the terminal : echo $M2 and not displya nothing , what can be?

Answer (score 0):

A process inherits its environment variables from its parent, at the time it was started. If you want to set some environment variable for all new processes, edit  `~/.profile` or `/etc/profile`, which are read by the login shell.